# Formatting the chapter title with the "Avant Garde" font

Tags: fonts, chapters, titles

I'm looking for formatting the chapter title with a Sanserif font like "Avant Garde".
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Preparation for unnumbered chapters
\newcommand{\unnumberedchapter}[1]{ 
    \cleardoublepage % To make sure the previous headers are passed
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1} % Also adds the chapter name to the Contents
    \fancyhead[RE]{{\bfseries #1}} % Headers for left pages
    \fancyhead[LO]{}}%Headers for right pages

% Formatting chapter heading
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontsize{18}{16}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\bfseries}{}{0pt}{
    \raisebox{-5mm}[0pt][0pt]{%<<
        \begin{minipage}{20mm}
            \centering{\mdseries\footnotesize\normalsize\textsc{}}\\[5pt]%
            \rule{10mm}{30mm}\hspace{-10mm}%
            \raisebox{23mm}{\parbox{10mm}{\centering\LARGE\textcolor{black}{\thechapter}}}%
        \end{minipage}
    }%
    \rule{\textwidth-22mm}{.4pt}\\%
    \hspace*{22mm}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-22mm}
}[\end{minipage}\vspace*{10mm}]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5
\begin{document}

\unnumberedchapter{Abstract} 
\chapter*{Abstract}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `pag` as family instead of `phv`, or load the avant package and then use \sffamily.

Comment: I tried with **pag** but it gives this error : " Font OT1/pag/m/n/18=pagk7t at 18.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \chapter*{Abstract} ". I tried also to load the avant package vainly.

Comment: Which tex system are you using and how do you compile?

Comment: I'm using **miktex 2.9** in windows 10 environment, and **TeXstudio** for compilation.

Comment: Check in the miktex console if you have the `avantgar` package installed.